# mousePressed con Android - Processing

Tags: android

Estoy haciendo una aplicación móvil con Processing 3.0.1 (última versión) para Android (la tablet que estoy usando es la Galaxy Tab 3 con Android 4.4.2 para runear el código)

Cuando ejecuto el código en el Java Mode va perfectamente. Pero cuando pongo el Android Mode todo funciona bien menos la función `mousePressed()` que es como si fuera con retraso, le tengo que hacer `tab` dos veces para que lleve a cabo algo que en Java Mode lo hace con solo un click.

Estoy usando este código que viene de ejemplo en la web de [Processing](https://processing.org/examples/button.html) para asegurarme que no tiene nada que ver con otras cosas que tengo implementadas.

¿Alguien sabe qué puede estar pasando? No encuentro ninguna referencia a esto.
Gracias!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Esto es un detalle muy conocido en Android, te recomiendo validar la ejecución

```
boolean ejecutaUnaVez;

void mousePressed() {
 if (mousePressed && ejecutaUnaVez== false) {
     ejecutaUnaVez= true;
 }
 if (mouseReleased) {
   ejecutaUnaVez= false;
 }
}
```

Comment: Hola, justo me he conectado para comentar algo parecido. He cambiado la función mousePressed() por mouseReleased() directamente y ha funcionado todo perfectamente.

Muchas gracias por tu aportación, lo tendré en cuenta para asegurarme y que funcione correctamente.